# OpenGL render interior faces with occlusion

Tags: opengl, occlusion, occlusion-culling

Is there a way in OpenGL to render only interior faces while exterior faces still cover/occlude the interior ones? To better understand what I want to accomplish, if I would slice a randomly positioned cylinder, I would see only an ellipse.

I have tried:

```
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_BACK);
```

But in this case I see the whole interior of the cylinder, while the exterior faces *just dissappear* without covering anything.

Thanks

Comment: I made a mistake in the commands that I posted. Edited them. I don't know if the solution is related to culling

Comment: Render the exterior faces with only the Z-buffer (glColorMask false), then render the interior faces normally (glColorMask true)?

Answer (score 2):

`GL_BACK` can't be "enabled". The culled faces are selected by [`glCullFace`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GLAPI/glCullFace):

<s>`glEnable(GL_BACK);`</s>

```
glCullFace(GL_BACK);
```

Note, `glEnable(GL_BACK)` will cause an `INVALID_ENUM` error.

Face culling depends on the winding order. See also [Face Culling](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Face_Culling).

e.g. If your faces are clockwise and you want to cull the back faces, then you have to:

```
glFrontFace(GL_CW​);
glCullFace(GL_BACK);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
```

Note, it is important, that all the faces have the same winding order (clockwise or counter clockwise).